# I can't understand the detail about "numpy.ndarray.dot" official document

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

The document is here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dot.html

I think the second output should be: array([[4.,  4.],
[4.,  4.]])

rather than: array([[8.,  8.],
[8.,  8.]])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result with all 8's is correct. Probably you confused elementwise multiplication and matrix multiplication. `numpy.dot` performs a matrix multiplication (when applied to 2D arrays).

```
a = np.eye(2)
b = np.ones((2,2)) * 2
print(a)
print(b)
```

will give you

```
[[1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]]
[[2. 2.]
 [2. 2.]]
```

So, `b` is a matrix consisting of all 2's. Now just do the matrix multiplication a * b * b and you get the matrix consisting of all 8's.

`a.dot(b)` will result in

```
[[2. 2.]
 [2. 2.]]
```

and `a.dot(b).dot(b)` will give

```
[[8. 8.]
 [8. 8.]]
```